# C# UWP - Wrong caret size when there is no text

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I have a `RichEditBox` and want to change the font size of the selection. When I don't select anything, and then change the font size, the caret size doesn't get bigger, until I start typing some characters (spaces don't work). When I delete all of those characters, the caret shrinks again, until I type some characters. Is there any possibility to change the caret size immediately, like in programs like Word?

```
ITextSelection selection = Editor.Document.Selection;
if(selection != null) {
    float fontSize;
    try {
        fontSize = (float) Convert.ToDouble(fontSizeBox.Text);
    } catch(FormatException) {
        fontSize = 11;
    }
    selection.CharacterFormat.Size = fontSize;
}
Editor.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: Hi, the specific height of the caret is determined by the height of the currently rendered text. So there is currently no way to change the default caret height when the text has not been entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by a trick using `PlaceholderText`

```
<RichEditBox PlaceholderText="Input your text" FontSize="52"/>
```

**Update:**

Well, I added some screenshot and did the test.
The caret did shrink a little when enter a new line. And it get bigger when `RichEditBox` changed from palceholder text to your own text.

This is really interesting.
I think this maybe a bug created by Microsoft.

Default:
[image]
The first line
[image]
Enter a new line
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround doesn't work for me sufficiently, since when the user enters a new line, the cursor size shrinks to the default value.